# intel driver on nvidia optimus laptop not recognizing internal display

Tags: xorg, nvidia, intel, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I have a ThinkPad W520 laptop with an nVidia optimus display. I recently upgraded my linux system to `linux-4.2.5` and `nvidia-358` and now I cannot get the internal display to be available for `X11`. Before that, I was able to use by my internal screen and an external DVI display simultaneously with the following setup:

I startup via `lightdm`. My `display_setup.sh` script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` is:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    Option "AccelMethod" "none"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

My `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows:

```
[  1399.370] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[  1399.370] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal LVDS
[  1399.370] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

Does that mean there is something wrong with my intel driver?

Any suggestions for further debugging?