# External Monitor on HDMI with a Hybrid (Nvidia Optimus) laptop

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, optimus, hybrid-graphics

Linux - Debian
uname -a >> output

```
Linux HomeLT 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a ASUS TUF FX504 GM.
It has a Intel i7 8750H and a GTX 1060
The problem is .. I can't use the external monitor I would plug into the HDMI port, by default.
The Intel iGPU,  UHD 630 is the default one that gets used unless I use this config file as specified in the following guide..

I have the "nvidia-driver" package installed.

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.26/README/randr14.html

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

Is there anyway to change this file to make it so that the computer books on the intel screen.. but also keeps the nvidia drivers "inactive" so that both monitors show up when I run the command "xrandr --auto"

I tried putting

```
Screen 0 "intel"
Inactive  "nvidia"
```

But that doesn't work.
Tried

```
Screen 0 "intel"
Screen 1 "nvidia
```

"
without the inactive line. That didn't quite work either.

I also have to run

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

after start up.

Can anyone help?

Similar topic
[intel driver on nvidia optimus laptop not recognizing internal display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250470/intel-driver-on-nvidia-optimus-laptop-not-recognizing-internal-display)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but according to the documentation the BusID format is

```
"%d@%d:%d:%d", bus, domain, device, function
```

I would try to replace the first : with a @.

See [NVIDIA's FAQ: "What is the format of a PCI Bus ID?"](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.26/README/faq.html#busid)